# Meaning of second number in error traceback

Tags: django

Sometimes I get an error traceback stating that there is invalid syntax.

```
/views.py', 166, 23, '
```

166 is the line where the debugger finds the problem. But what is the second number, 23, supposed to tell me?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but I'd say it's the character position on the line where the syntax error was detected.